# Asymptotic Analysis compare f and g

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, asymptotic-complexity

I have to compare the function f and g to find whether:

f ∈ Θ(g), f ∈ O(g),
f ∈ o(g), f ∈ Ω(g), 
f ∈ ω(g), g ∈ Θ(f),
 g ∈ O(f), g ∈ o(f),
 g ∈ Ω(f), g ∈ ω(f).

f(n) = n^2/ log n and g(n) = n log n.

As my understanding for the asymptotic analysis I got that:

```
    f(n) = O(g(n)) is like a =< b
    f(n) = Ω(g(n)) is like a => b
    f(n) = Θ(g(n)) is like a == b
    f(n) = o(g(n)) is like a < b
    f(n) = ω(g(n)) is like a > b
```

So now I plot the f(n) and g(n) and I saw that for small values of n, f(n) is bigger but for very large values of n the g(n) is bigger, so in this sense when the n is bigger is more important since the algorithms have to be general, so this means that the f(n) and g(n) are:

```
f ∈ Ω(g) and f ∈ ω(g) and g ∈ O(f) and g ∈ o(f)
```

Now my question is this the right way to find these so to plot the function and see which is bigger and does that mean that when they intersect they are equal?

Comment: No, this is not the correct approach. See how these expressions are defined and work from there.

Comment: Firstly what are "a" and "b"? Secondly, a function cannot be big-Ω and little-ω simultaneously.

Comment: a and b meaning a = f(n) and b = g(n)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Can you explain why, for example if I have my f(n) = n^3 and my g(n)=3n then if we do the Omega test we get f(n) => c*g(n) which is n^3 >= 12n which is CORRECT and then if we do the little-ω test we get lim n^3/3n = INF which is also CORRECT, so why two functions cannot be big Omega and Little ω in the same time?

Comment: Because big-Ω's equality case contradicts that of little-ω, so it is strictly little-ω.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog actually, f in omega(g) implies f in Omega(g) so they can well be true at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding looks wrong in these two cases:

```
f(n) = o(g(n)) is like a < b
f(n) = ω(g(n)) is like a > b
```

It's better to visualize these cases like:

```
f(n) = o(g(n)) is like a << b
f(n) = ω(g(n)) is like a >> b
```

Sorry to say, the exact mathematical meaning of these two symbols `<<` ("much less") and `>>` ("much greater") is not defined.

So, in general, instead of plotting two functions you can think in terms of the **limit** of the ratio `f(n)/g(n)` of these two functions (when `n` goes to positive infinity):

- if this limit is zero, then `f = o(g)`
- if this limit is a positive constant, then `f = Θ(g)`
- if this limit is a positive infinity, then `f = ω(g)`

Of course, it's just a hint - your answer to any question about asymptotic relationship between two functions will look much better if you use an exact mathematical definition of this relationship.